# DevExpress GroupControl Scrolling issue

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, janus

When using a Janus UIGroupBox the scroll is working fine when hovering over controls and when using a devExpress GroupControl everything is working as before as like using a Janus control except the hover over scroll. [This is how a GroupControl looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtQss.jpg)
The scroll is working outside the control and when hovered over it doesnt work.

Comment: What the hell is a "hover over scoll"?

Comment: when u hover over a control and try to scroll.

Comment: I assume you mean you try to scroll with the mouse wheel, don't you?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what im trying to do.

Comment: Okay, hard to guess but I gave you my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported and probably never will be:

- [GroupControl and the AutoScroll property](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q211382)

But there's a workaround - just place a `XtraScrollableControl` in your `GroupControl` and your fine:

- [Group Control Scrollbars](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q389708)

Comment: That doesnt serve my purpose as I'm not trying to scroll within the GroupControl. The scroll should work when there are mutiple groupControl boxes and should be able to scroll till the bottom of the form.

Comment: This would have been good to know from the start. So then, you could catch these mousewheel-events in the GroupControl and forward it to its parent scroll container if there's no property on the GroupControl to ignore the mousewheel.